# Можно ли сказать "менее современный"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Внезапно подумалось: а как это — "менее современный"? Если современный, то значит, что предмет соответствует данному времени. А если он "менее современный", то он уже устарел. А то получается какая-то "осетрина второй свежести"))))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Степени сравнения образуют качественные прилагательные. Прилагательное современный - качественное. Образует антоним с приставкой НЕ, сочетается с наречием "очень" . Так что и степени сравнения образует тоже. Причем так было и до бурного развития цифровой техники. Более или менее современными могли быть, например, модели одежды.

Comment: Сказать, что футболка посовременней сорочки, я ещё могу. А вот, что рубашка-сорочка менее современна чем футболка, уже как-то не получается. Всё-таки, для того чтобы быть менее современной, вещь должна обладать ещё и качественными характеристиками, которые возможно превзойти. У моделей одежды, в отличии, например, от ткани, таких характеристик нет.

Comment: А разные модели у той же рубашки могут быть? Как у Айфона...

Comment: Могут. Но они будут модными или не модными, современными или ретро. Как из двух современных рубашек, определить более современную я не знаю. У техники в более современной модели добавлен новый функционал или же усовершенствован старый.

Answer (score 6):

Есть Айфон 4, а есть Айфон 5. Оба они достаточно современны. Тем не менее четвёртая  модель менее современна, нежели пятая. Сравнение современности той или иной вещи появилось сравнительно недавно, когда выпускать новые модели, прежде всего техники, стали быстрее, чем приходить в негодность старые.